# Xcode cannot load SwiftUI Preview Canvas with error "Loading a plug-in failed."

Tags: xcode, swiftui

When opening Xcode I get a popup with the following error:

> Loading a plug-in failed.
>
> The plug-in “com.apple.dt.PreviewsXcode” at path “/Applications/Xcode_14_2.app/Contents/PlugIns/PreviewsXcode.framework” could not be loaded.  The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged.
> The plug-in or one of its prerequisite plug-ins may be missing or damaged and may need to be reinstalled.

There is a more detailed error message:

> dlopen(/Applications/Xcode_14_2.app/Contents/PlugIns/PreviewsXcode.framework/PreviewsXcode, 0x0109): Symbol not found: _$s9ChronoKit34WidgetPreviewHostingViewControllerCMn
> Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode_14_2.app/Contents/PlugIns/PreviewsXcode.framework/Versions/A/PreviewsXcode
> Expected in: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ChronoKit.framework/Versions/A/ChronoKit

I am using Xcode 14.2 on macOS 14.1.1 on an Apple Silicon computer.
In order to be able to use this outdated Xcode version I need to start Xcode from the command line like this:

```
/Applications/Xcode_14_2.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode ; exit;
```

The same procedure is working on some colleagues' machine so I don't believe it is related.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can pop up if you use incompatible versions, e.g. a 15 plugin into an 14.2 install.

Copy and paste the preview plugin to the Xcode 14.2 install to rectify this.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried simply reinstalling or upgrading Xcode. Also that looks like an old version of Xcode compared to macOS. Why not just update them to the newest version.

Comment: I need to keep the outdated version to support a legacy project. Also, yes, I did reinstall Xcode - no change.